# Reformatting of strings

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have XML were some of the date and datetime strings are delivered in somtimes exotic formats:

> DDMMYYYYHHMM (Hours in 24 hour format)

I was trying to create a User Defined Function in a XSLT to be able to reformat such a string (I know how to do this in other languages but I don't have a clue yet on how to do this in XSLT). My idea would be something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="udf:reFormat('230820141345','DDMMCCYYHHmm','HH:mm:00')"/>
```

would result in:

```
13:45:00
```

and

```
<xsl:value-of select="udf:reFormat('230820141345','DDMMCCYYHHmm','CCYY-MM-DD')"/>
```

would result in:

```
2014-08-23
```

Comment: My first idea was to locate what is located on the location of "CCYY" in the input string and put that on the location of "CCYY" in the output string. In that case the letters (in the format string) used would not matter that much.

Comment: Which version of XSLT 2.0 is that? User defined functions sounds like XSLT 2.0 and in that case I would start by converting the input format `DDMMYYYYHHMM` into an `xs:dateTime` and for further formatting I would use the built-in http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date functions.

Comment: That is my backup plan. But was looking for a more "flexible" solution because in the middleware there are lots of date-time conversion challanges. It is XSLT 2.0 within Sonic.

Comment: Why would Martin's suggestion not be flexible? There is a bunch of useful existing functions, once your date is of type `xs:dateTime`.

Comment: Martins answer is absolutly flexible! The challange I see is that date, time and datetime fields are not uniform so I need to process each type individually to make it a date, time or datetime in XSLT. After that the formatting possibilities are as flexible as I would need. But I was trying to eliminate the need to transform it first before formatting. Like I wrote that is possible the method I will be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment the obvious way would be to parse the data to xs:dateTime, never the less here's a function that does what you want:

```
<xsl:function name="udf:reFormat">
    <xsl:param name="in"/>
    <xsl:param name="inPattern"/>
    <xsl:param name="outPattern"/>

    <!-- analyze $outPattern to find occurrence of any sequence of same charachter -->
    <xsl:analyze-string select="$outPattern" regex="(\w)\1+">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:variable name="match" select="."/>
            <!-- check if $match is in $inPattern -->
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($inPattern, $match)">
                    <!-- get position of $match in $inPattern -->
                    <xsl:variable name="positionInPattern"
                        select="string-length(substring-before($inPattern,$match))+1"/>
                    <!-- get substring from $in -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($in, $positionInPattern, string-length($match))"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>

</xsl:function>
```

Comment: Great solution, although you need a seperator between the pattern chars (udfReformat("121320142244","DDMMCCYYHHmm","HH:mm:00") works but  udfReformat("121320142244","DDMMCCYYHHmm","HHmm00") fails). This works for me if I need a simple transformation without carring to much about transforming the input to a date(time) first.

Comment: You're right, that was my bad on the regex... I adjusted the regex now it should work without separators too.

Comment: Great, This works perfectly for fast transformations.